# Toda função retorna um objeto em Python?

Tags: python, funções, característica-linguagem

Em Python, é comum afirmar que todos os tipos de dados são objetos. Uma prova disso é que [a própria referência da documentação afirma que "*Todos os dados em Python são representados por objetos*"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types).

Sabendo que as funções sempre retornam algo (`None`, quando o retorno não é definido), seria correto afirmar que as funções são um tipo de objeto, que podem ou não realizar uma tarefa, mas que obrigatoriamente possuem um objeto como retorno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem duas perguntas aí.

Toda função retorna um objeto, mesmo quando retorna `None`, ele é um objeto. O conceito matemático de função é sempre resultar em algo e Python respeita isso.

Quanto a uma função ser um objeto costuma ser mais complicado. Dentro da especificação da linguagem ela é. Pela característica dinâmica da linguagem você pode mudar tudo nela.

Essas linguagens, geralmente chamadas de *script* estruturam objetos como dicionários e por isso possuem bastante flexibilidade. Muita gente não sabe disto.

Algumas linguagens são tão flexíveis que tratam a própria função como um objeto. Eu sabia de algumas, mas não sabia de Python, agora sei graças ao hkotsubo abaixo.

E é um pouco estranho uma função não realizar uma tarefa. Até é possível fazer isso, mas não costuma fazer sentido em uma aplicação. Até pode fazer sentido em algum experimento ou um caso que tem a obrigação de ter a função por alguma razão que será chamada (portanto o nome tem que estar disponível) e tem um cenário que não deveria executar nada, mas não seria o normal na maioria dos cenários de uso da mesma função.

Comment: Eu concorco com você quando diz que uma função não é um objeto. Do meu ponto de vista, funções seriam semelhantes a loops e condicionais, ou seja, uma estrutura que te permite coordenar as instruções do código, por exemplo, receba estes parametros, realize estas tarefas e retorne estes valores, Você concorda ? Porém, de acordo com o que observo, o correto seria que funções são um tipo de objeto que retorna outro objeto. E referente a realizar tarefas, um função pode ser declarada sem argumentos ou instruções e mesmo assim ela,por padrão, vai retornar None. Estou correto ?

Comment: @Maniero, voce diria que as identity functions da programacao funcional (que simplesmente retornam o argumento recebido) realizam uma tarefa ou não?

Comment: O [Data Model do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#user-defined-functions) diz que "*A user-defined function **object** is created by a function definition*".

E em vários pontos usa-se o termo "*function objects*" para se referir às funções.

Eu entendo então que funções são objetos sim.
Tanto que elas têm um método (`__call__`) e podem ter atributos: https://ideone.com/A2RHI4

Comment: @LuisJr. não diria que são bem iguais. Está correto na última afirmação.

Comment: @bfavaretto boa questão, eu teria que analisar mais profundamente.

Comment: @hkotsubo é verdade, dei uma consertada.

Comment: @hkotsubo E da mesma forma que as funções, os dicionários também podem ser considerados objetos. Eu acredito que essa flexibilidade permite enormes contribuições para a propria linguagem, porque se todos os tipos são objetos e você tem acesso aos construtores, você pode debugar e melhorar a linguagem com mais liberdade. Eu me considero novato em programação e te agradeço muito pelo comentário, expandiu minha visão.